# PHP : Sum up the result of some "echo do_shortcode"

Tags: php, wordpress, sum, echo, shortcode

I'v been searching all the website / web with to achieve that, with no luck. I'm not a developper at all also, so the few information that I could get, didn't help me either.

The situation : I have some Wordpress plugins, that allows me to generate some numbers with shortcode. For example I have [shortcode1] from one plugin, and [shortcode2] from another, each of them returning a dynamic number.

I'm using PHP in my pages, to display that number, by a simple "php echo do_shortcode('[shortcode1]');" , same for shortcode 2, and it works well.

I'm trying to sum up the value that is returning from these 2 shortocdes. Lets say shortcode1 = 10 and shortcode2 = 20, I need to display "30".

I tried sending the "do_shortcodes" into arguments, then using "sum", or use "+", but none of this worked, and actually it makes sense because when doing so, I am attributing the shortcode to this argument, not the actual result of it. Knowing that, I then tried to apply "echo do_shortcode" to the argument instead, to save the result instead of the actual shortcode. But apparently it's not correct to do it, or I don't have the way to do it.

I hope I could explained properly, any idea of how I could achieve this ? (Wishing there could be an answer as simple as 1+1=2 :) )

Thanks in advance

Comment: you'll need to show your code, for do shortcode and the result (html visible as well)

Comment: Hi David, the code I'm using to display the number : echo do_shortcode('[facebook-followers]');. As a result it will return a number, lets say 10. But tomorrow it can be 11, 12, 13... the number returned by the shortcode is dynamic.

Comment: the actual number doesn't matter, what matters is why you cannot add it, i mean if it returns a number, it is a number, do_shortcode('[something]') + do_shortcode('[something]') should give you a number back. But as is all we can do is guess what your shortcode returns, its not going to get solved that way!

Comment: So I tried to write the code that you'v given : do_shortcode('[something1]') + do_shortcode('[something2]'), and it returns 1020 (which is basically the 1st one : 10, followed by the 2nd one : 20. They are not beeing summed up). The HTML returned is the same. I'm not sure how this can help, otherwise maybe I'm not understanding correctly what you mean by "return".

Comment: so its being treated as a string. You need to convert this to a number, but offhand its being treated as a string because there is html tags around the number. Learn how to use inspect element in chrome or firefox, this will show you what is actually being output, what you see on screen is the rendered data, and html tags are not visible. Return means returned data from a function.

Comment: The HTML returned is the same. Meaning the output is free of HTML tags. here is what the HTML code looks like : http://screencast.com/t/lKNmYA9n6P, and this is how my code with the shortcode looks like : http://screencast.com/t/yTNRxR1b8i.

Yes I agree it's beeing treated as a string, not as an actual number, That's why "sum" or "+" couldn't work.

Looks like there is no simple solution for that, nevermind, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure numbers only like this, but do_shortcode() is the wrong approach for what you want to do in most cases. The following is not efficient in terms of programming but will do what you want. You could just generate a variable and use that but i suppose you have your reasons. Anyway...

```
$a = (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',do_shortcode('[whatever]'));
$b =  (int) preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',do_shortcode('[whateverb]'));

$c= $a + $b;

echo $c;
```